# Setting cookies in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a small petition project, I would like to set a cookie when a user signs it, so if he tries to access the page again, it should redirect him already to a "thanks page". If the user didn't, then he can proceed to sign it.
I'm getting the `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error, maybe someone understands what I'm doing wrong. Down below the js code.

```js
const express = require("express");
const { getSignatures, addSignature } = require("./db.js");

const app = express();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static("./public"));
const hb = require("express-handlebars");
app.engine("handlebars", hb());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/petition");
});

app.get("/petition", (req, res) => {
    let hasSigned = req.cookies.petition_signed;
    if (!hasSigned) {
        res.render("petition", {
            layout: "main",
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/thanks");
    }
});

app.post("/petition", (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, signature } = req.body;
    //console.log("req.body: ", req.body);

    if (firstName === "" || lastName === "" || signature === "") {
        res.render("petitionerror", {
            error: "Please fill out all the elements before submitting",
        });
    } else {
        addSignature(firstName, lastName, signature).then((data) => {
            res.cookie("petition_signed", "yes");
            console.log(data);
        });
        res.redirect("/thanks");
    }
});

app.get("/thanks", (req, res) => {
    res.render("thankyou", {
        layout: "main",
    });
});
app.get("/signers", (req, res) => {
    getSignatures().then((data) => {
        res.render("signers", { success: true, rows: data.rows });
    });
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("listening on 8080"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it structured, it is trying to do `res.cookie` after `res.redirect` because addSignature is an asynchronous function.

```
    addSignature(firstName, lastName, signature).then((data) => {
        res.cookie("petition_signed", "yes");
        console.log(data);
        res.redirect("/thanks");
    });
```

You need to ensure `res.cookie` is called prior to `redirect` (which returns headers to the client)

Comment: I moved the res.cookie and res.redirect outside the addSignature function and it's working. Still a bit newbie with promises :)